# Content updating slow on screen though FPS is 60

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am loading a menu in which i have 7 layers through which i swipe. On first load the swiping is smooth at 60fps, but i then pop the scene and push it again, the swiping is very slow, though the app displays 60fps, and the ccTouchesMoved is called roughly at the same interval as on the first load.

On each layer, i add some statical CCSprites and a CCMenu.

All items are deallocated, and i am testing the app on ipad 3 (so speed isn't quite an issue).

I presume that the cause is more on the settings part and would like to find a solution for it. Here are my touch methods, if it helps:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    //Swipe Detection Part 1
    firstTouch = location;

}


-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch * touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    for(int i=0;i<[layerList count];i++)
    {

        [[layerList objectAtIndex:i] setPosition:CGPointMake((i-currentLayer)*winSize.width + (location.x - firstTouch.x),0) ];
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch * touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    //Swipe Detection Part 2
    lastTouch = location;

    //Swipe Detection Part 2
    lastTouch = location;

    //Minimum length of the swipe
    float swipeLength = ccpDistance(firstTouch, lastTouch);

    //Check if the swipe is a left swipe and long enough
    if (firstTouch.x > lastTouch.x && swipeLength > 60) {
        [self doStuffLeft];
    }
    else if (firstTouch.x < lastTouch.x && abs(swipeLength) > 60) {
        [self doStuffRight];
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, [CCDirector sharedInstance] was paused.